# Fastest save and load options for a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, io

I have a script that generates two-dimensional `numpy` arrays with `dtype=float` and shape on the order of `(1e3, 1e6)`.  Right now I'm using `np.save` and `np.load` to perform IO operations with the arrays.  However, these functions take several seconds for each array.  Are there faster methods for saving and loading the entire arrays (i.e., without making assumptions about their contents and reducing them)?  I'm open to converting the arrays to another type before saving as long as the data are retained exactly.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For really big arrays, I've heard about several solutions, and they mostly on being lazy on the I/O :

- [NumPy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), maps big arrays to binary form

  - Pros :

    - No dependency other than Numpy
    - Transparent replacement of `ndarray` (Any class accepting ndarray accepts `memmap` )
  - Cons :

    - Chunks of your array are limited to 2.5G
    - Still limited by Numpy throughput
- Use Python bindings for HDF5, a bigdata-ready file format, like [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/index.html) or [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/)

  - Pros :

    - Format supports compression, indexing, and other super nice features
    - Apparently the ultimate PetaByte-large file format
  - Cons :

    - Learning curve of having a hierarchical format ?
    - Have to define what your performance needs are (see later)
- [Python's  pickling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) system (out of the race, mentioned for Pythonicity rather than speed)

  - Pros:

    - It's Pythonic ! (haha)
    - Supports all sorts of objects
  - Cons:

    - Probably slower than others (because aimed at any objects not arrays)

---

## Numpy.memmap

From the docs of [NumPy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) :

> Create a memory-map to an array stored in a binary file on disk.
>
> Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory
>
> The memmap object can be used anywhere an ndarray is accepted. Given any memmap `fp` , `isinstance(fp, numpy.ndarray)`  returns True.

---

## HDF5 arrays

From the [h5py doc](http://www.h5py.org/)

> Lets you store huge amounts of numerical data, and easily manipulate that data from NumPy. For example, you can slice into multi-terabyte datasets stored on disk, as if they were real NumPy arrays. Thousands of datasets can be stored in a single file, categorized and tagged however you want.

The format supports compression of data in various ways (more bits loaded for same I/O read), but this means that the data becomes less easy to query individually, but in your case (purely loading / dumping arrays) it might be efficient

Comment: did you do the profiling? how was h5py? Im having some trouble, gets considerably slower when having thousands of datasets in the same file...

Comment: i heard hdf5 doesnt support threading/processing/celery, how do you get around that

Comment: @PirateApp [Threading example from h5py](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/examples/threading_example.py) shows otherwise? Do open up a separate question if you need additional specific help

Comment: From my experience using [deepdish](https://github.com/uchicago-cs/deepdish), partial loading is considerably slower and inefficient. Ended up loading my entire datasets into memory.

Answer (score 43):

I've compared a few methods using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) (one of my projects). Here are the results:

#### Writing

[image]

For large arrays, all methods are about equally fast. The file sizes are also equal which is to be expected since the input array are random doubles and hence hardly compressible.

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
from sys import version_info

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import perfplot
import pickle
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import h5py
import tables
import zarr


def write_numpy(data):
    np.save("out.npy", data)


def write_hdf5(data):
    with h5py.File("out.h5", "w") as f:
        f.create_dataset("data", data=data)


def write_netcdf(data):
    with netCDF4.Dataset("out.nc", "w") as nc:
        nc.createDimension("len_data", len(data))
        ncdata = nc.createVariable(
            "mydata",
            "float64",
            ("len_data",),
        )
        ncdata[:] = data


def write_pickle(data):
    with open("out.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)


def write_pytables(data):
    with tables.open_file("out-pytables.h5", mode="w") as f:
        gcolumns = f.create_group(f.root, "columns", "data")
        f.create_array(gcolumns, "data", data, "data")


def write_zarr_zarr(data):
    zarr.save_array("out.zarr", data)


def write_zarr_zip(data):
    zarr.save_array("out.zip", data)


def write_zarr_zarr_uncompressed(data):
    zarr.save_array("out-uncompressed.zarr", data, compressor=None)


def write_zarr_zip_uncompressed(data):
    zarr.save_array("out-uncompressed.zip", data)


def setup(n):
    data = np.random.rand(n)
    n[...] = data.nbytes
    return data


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[
        write_numpy,
        write_hdf5,
        write_netcdf,
        write_pickle,
        write_pytables,
        write_zarr_zarr,
        write_zarr_zip,
        write_zarr_zarr_uncompressed,
        write_zarr_zip_uncompressed,
    ],
    title="write comparison",
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(28)],
    xlabel="data.nbytes",
    equality_check=None,
)

plt.text(
    0.0,
    -0.3,
    ", ".join(
        [
            f"Python {version_info.major}.{version_info.minor}.{version_info.micro}",
            f"h5py {h5py.__version__}",
            f"netCDF4 {netCDF4.__version__}",
            f"NumPy {np.__version__}",
            f"PyTables {tables.__version__}",
            f"Zarr {zarr.__version__}",
        ]
    ),
    transform=plt.gca().transAxes,
    fontsize="x-small",
    verticalalignment="top",
)

b.save("out-write.png")
b.show()
```

#### Reading

[image]

pickles, pytables and hdf5 are roughly equally fast; pickles and zarr are slower for large arrays.

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import perfplot
import pickle
import numpy
import h5py
import tables
import zarr


def setup(n):
    data = numpy.random.rand(n)
    # write all files
    #
    numpy.save("out.npy", data)
    #
    f = h5py.File("out.h5", "w")
    f.create_dataset("data", data=data)
    f.close()
    #
    with open("test.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
    #
    f = tables.open_file("pytables.h5", mode="w")
    gcolumns = f.create_group(f.root, "columns", "data")
    f.create_array(gcolumns, "data", data, "data")
    f.close()
    #
    zarr.save("out.zip", data)


def npy_read(data):
    return numpy.load("out.npy")


def hdf5_read(data):
    f = h5py.File("out.h5", "r")
    out = f["data"][()]
    f.close()
    return out


def pickle_read(data):
    with open("test.pkl", "rb") as f:
        out = pickle.load(f)
    return out


def pytables_read(data):
    f = tables.open_file("pytables.h5", mode="r")
    out = f.root.columns.data[()]
    f.close()
    return out


def zarr_read(data):
    return zarr.load("out.zip")


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[
        npy_read,
        hdf5_read,
        pickle_read,
        pytables_read,
        zarr_read,
    ],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(27)],
    xlabel="len(data)",
)
b.save("out2.png")
b.show()
```

Comment: Amazing, can you update the figures for python 3.8, is there any change?

Answer (score 25):

Here is a comparison with PyTables.

I cannot get up to `(int(1e3), int(1e6)` due to memory restrictions.
Therefore, I used a smaller array:

```
data = np.random.random((int(1e3), int(1e5)))
```

NumPy `save`:

```
%timeit np.save('array.npy', data)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.26 s per loop
```

NumPy `load`:

```
%timeit data2 = np.load('array.npy')
1 loops, best of 3: 3.43 s per loop
```

PyTables writing:

```
%%timeit
with tables.open_file('array.tbl', 'w') as h5_file:
    h5_file.create_array('/', 'data', data)

1 loops, best of 3: 4.16 s per loop
```

PyTables reading:

```
 %%timeit
 with tables.open_file('array.tbl', 'r') as h5_file:
      data2 = h5_file.root.data.read()

 1 loops, best of 3: 3.51 s per loop
```

The numbers are very similar. So no real gain wit PyTables here.
But we are pretty close to the maximum writing and reading rate of my SSD.

Writing:

```
Maximum write speed: 241.6 MB/s
PyTables write speed: 183.4 MB/s
```

Reading:

```
Maximum read speed: 250.2
PyTables read speed: 217.4
```

Compression does not really help due to the randomness of the data:

```
%%timeit
FILTERS = tables.Filters(complib='blosc', complevel=5)
with tables.open_file('array.tbl', mode='w', filters=FILTERS) as h5_file:
    h5_file.create_carray('/', 'data', obj=data)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.08 s per loop
```

Reading of the compressed data becomes a bit slower:

```
%%timeit
with tables.open_file('array.tbl', 'r') as h5_file:
    data2 = h5_file.root.data.read()

1 loops, best of 3: 4.01 s per loop
```

This is different for regular data:

```
 reg_data = np.ones((int(1e3), int(1e5)))
```

Writing is significantly faster:

```
%%timeit
FILTERS = tables.Filters(complib='blosc', complevel=5)
with tables.open_file('array.tbl', mode='w', filters=FILTERS) as h5_file:
    h5_file.create_carray('/', 'reg_data', obj=reg_data)
```

1 loops, best of 3: 849 ms per loop

The same holds true for reading:

```
%%timeit
with tables.open_file('array.tbl', 'r') as h5_file:
    reg_data2 = h5_file.root.reg_data.read()

1 loops, best of 3: 1.7 s per loop
```

**Conclusion**:  The more regular your data the faster it should get using PyTables.

Answer (score 14):

According to my experience, np.save()&np.load() is the fastest solution when trasfering data between hard disk and memory so far.
I've heavily relied my data loading on database and HDFS system before I realized this conclusion.
My tests shows that:
The database data loading(from hard disk to memory) bandwidth could be around 50 MBps(Byets/Second), but the np.load() bandwidth is almost same as my hard disk maximum bandwidth: 2GBps(Byets/Second). Both test environments use the simplest data structure.

And I don't think it's a problem to use several seconds to loading an array with shape: (1e3, 1e6). E.g.
Your array shape is (1000, 1000000), its data type is float128, then the pure data size is (128/8)*1000*1,000,000=16,000,000,000=16GBytes
and if it takes 4 seconds,
Then your data loading bandwidth is 16GBytes/4Seconds = 4GBps.
SATA3 maximum bandwidth is 600MBps=0.6GBps, your data loading bandwidth is already 6 times of it, your data loading performance almost could compete with [DDR's maximum bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_data_rate),  what else do you want?

So my final conclusion is:

**Don't use python's Pickle, don't use any database, don't use any big data system to store your data into hard disk, if you could use np.save() and np.load(). These two functions are the fastest solution to transfer data between harddisk and memory so far.**

I've also tested the [HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) , and found that it's much slower than np.load() and np.save(), so use np.save()&np.load() if you've enough DDR memory in your platfrom.

Comment: If you can't reach reach the maximum bandwith of your storage device using HDF5 you have usualy made something wrong. And there are many things that can go wrong. (chunk-cache,chunkshape, fancy indexing,...)

Comment: max9111, no, I don't agree. Some restrictions come from the software framework, only fine-tuning your system couldn't impove the performance. After I found the huge performance difference between the np.load() and mysql on the data loading, I believe software framework is very important, a correct choice could help us saving lots of time.

Comment: Try for example this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48997927/4045774 with and without compression (the compression limits at about 500-800 MB/s. For well compressible data you can get a lot more throuput with HDF 5 on a HDD or even a SATA3 SSD.  But the main advantage is reading or writing parts of array along abitrary axis at sequential IO-Speed. If IO-speed realy matters, it is also likely that the array is bigger than the RAM...

Comment: max9111, thanks for your reply. I've tested the code in stackoverflow.com/a/48997927/4045774. And I've found that your codes test result on my computer is 298MBps, but after I changed dset_train_bottle() to np.save(), the test result is 2381MBps, it means HDF5 is much slower in my environment than using np.save(). If you test np.save(), I believe you'll get a even higher number than me, maybe 4~5GBps

Comment: Believe me, np.save()&np.load() is much much faster than you imagine, after found this, I hate why I couldn't find it earlier. I waste lots of time to test new tools and software plaform to store dataset and load dataset from hard disk. But the best solution is just the simpliest way.

Comment: @ClockZHONG, thanks for your post, how about DataFrames?

Comment: @wh408, I don't know. I've not test it, if you want to know, you could use the test framework provided by max9111. It's very easy to get a confirmed anwser in SW domain, because we could make it happen at once.

Comment: What if you want random access of the array values on disk?  I'm assuming you would have to go to HDF5 for that use case?

Comment: @Duane no, It's impossible, if you want to random access a small part of data from a very very big number, our only choices are database, HDF5 or some other mechanism which could support us to randomly access harddisk. I suggest to use np.load() only when we have enough DDR memory space and our data is not so huge, at least our data could be put into our memory space.

Comment: how about numpy.memmap ? any experience?

Comment: @MartinMeeser I've no experience to use numpy.memmap, but according its official website here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html, It seems very similar with np.load(), the only difference is that np.load() only could load a whole darray, but np.memmap() could load a section of a whole darray(but with some limitations, e.g the loading data must stored togather in the file). So it seems their performance should be same.

Answer (score 5):

I created a benchmarking tool and produced a benchmark of the various loading/saving methods using python 3.10. I ran it on a fast NVMe (with >6GB/s transfer rate so the measurements here are not disk I/O bound). The size of the tested numpy array was varied from tiny to 32GB. The results can be seen [here](https://omasoud.github.io/np-array-io-bench/).
The github repo for the tool is [here](https://github.com/omasoud/np-array-io-bench).

The results vary, and are affected by the array size; and some methods perform data compression so there's a tradeoff for those. Here is an idea of I/O rate (more results in via link above):

[image: IO Rate]

Legend (for the saves):
np: `np.save()`, npz: `np.savez()`, npzc: `np.savez_compressed()`, hdf5: `h5py.File().create_dataset()`, pickle: `pickle.dump()`, zarr_zip: `zarr.save_array()` w/ `.zip` extension, zarr_zip: `zarr.save_array()` w/ `.zarr` extension, pytables: `tables.open_file().create_array()`, fast_np: uses [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70886904/5659969) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to see torch.load and torch.save were considered as optimal or near-optimal according to the benchmarks here, yet I find it quite slow for what it's supposed to do. So I gave it a try and came up with a much faster alternative: [fastnumpyio](https://github.com/divideconcept/fastnumpyio)

Running 100000 save/load iterations of a 3x64x64 float array (common scenario in computer vision) I achieved the following speedup over numpy.save and numpy.load (I suppose numpy.load is so slow because it has to parse text data first ?):

Windows 11, Python 3.9.5, Numpy 1.22.0, Intel Core i7-9750H:

```
numpy.save: 0:00:01.656569
fast_numpy_save: 0:00:00.398236
numpy.load: 0:00:16.281941
fast_numpy_load: 0:00:00.308100
```

Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.9.7, Numpy 1.21.4, Intel Core i7-9750H:

```
numpy.save: 0:00:01.887152
fast_numpy_save: 0:00:00.745052
numpy.load: 0:00:16.368871
fast_numpy_load: 0:00:00.381135
```

macOS 12.0.1, Python 3.9.5, Numpy 1.21.2, Apple M1:

```
numpy.save: 0:00:01.268598
fast_numpy_save: 0:00:00.449448
numpy.load: 0:00:11.303569
fast_numpy_load: 0:00:00.318216
```

With larger arrays (3x512x512), fastnumpyio is still slightly faster for save and 2 times faster for load.

Comment: Impressive that `np.save` can be made 2 x faster with just this single line of code? https://github.com/divideconcept/fastnumpyio/blob/main/fastnumpyio.py#L7 Is it still the case in recent versions of numpy? Did you consider make a pull request into numpy @RobinLobel? It would be interesting.

Comment: Hi, I just updated fastnumpyio with more functionalities - and yes it's still way faster even with the latest version of numpy...
At least I'll let the numpy team know about this repo, in case they want to do something with it :)