# Numpy save taking too long in large dataset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, io, h5py

I'm trying to save a numpy array to disk but the saving process never seems to end, and the terminal keeps hanging without showing me the final print message of 'done'. I can tell the array is correctly formed by checking its `shape` right before the saving function.
I wonder if I'm doing anything wrong or if this would be expected with `numpy.save` given the size of the dataset.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this either with numpy or h5py?

```
# Xy_array is a 3D array of 10,000 images, each 224 x 224

Xy_array = np.asarray(lst)
f = open('./data/data.npy', 'wb')
np.save(f, Xy_array)
f.close()
print('done')
```

Comment: What's `Xy_array.dtype`?

Comment: good point-- it's a `dtype('O')` -- does this mean I can't save a numpy object?

Comment: Isn't `dtype('O')` objects? Apparently [`numpy.save()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) can pickle, but that might produce massive amounts of data, as your array is already 595 million items, IIUC.

Comment: maybe this anwser might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329726/fastest-save-and-load-options-for-a-numpy-array