# Memory error pickle dump while saving/loading data from/into disk

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, hdf5, h5py

l have a dataset of 40,000 examples `dataset=(40.000,2048)`. After a process l would like to store and load dataset efficiently. Dataset is in an numpy format

l used pickle to store this `dataset` but it takes time to store and more time to load it. I even get memory error.

l tried to split the `dataset` into several sample as follow :

```
with open('dataset_10000.sav', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(train_frames[:10000], handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('dataset_20000.sav', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(train_frames[10000:20000], handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('dataset_30000.sav', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(train_frames[20000:30000], handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('dataset_35000.sav', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(train_frames[30000:35000], handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('dataset_40000.sav', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(train_frames[35000:], handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

However l get a memory error and its too heavy.

What is the best/optimized way to save/load such a huge data from/into disk ?

Comment: Is this a numpy array?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes as described in my first paragraph. It's a numpy array

Comment: Using HDF5. Please add how you want to read your data after writing. For example iterating over the first or the second dimension.

Comment: over the first dimension

Comment: I think in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954998/4045774  should answer the question how to read and write data into the HDF5 format. If not feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

For `numpy.ndarray` objects, use [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) which you should prefer over `pickle` anyway, since it is more portable.It should be faster and require less memory in the serialization process.

You can then load it with [`numpy.load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) which even provides a memmap option, allowing you to work with arrays that are larger than can fit into memory.

Comment: can l save at one time . l mean all the 40000 data  ? and what is the extension of the file while using numpy.save ?

Comment: @Joseph yes, save all of it. you can call it whatever you want, but the extension is `.npy` which is a `numpy` specific binary serialization format which retains information like endianess to make your serialized data portable. Note, this is preferable to `pickle` since `pickle` would require essentially a duplication of the data in memory.

Comment: what about hdf5 ?

Comment: @Joseph what about it?

Comment: what is the fmt option in numpy save ? is it the same of float and  string ?

Comment: @Joseph what? there is no `fmt` option. It isn't like `np.savetxt`, which essentially creates a csv. This is a `numpy` -specific binary serialization format which allows your arrays to be reconstructed correctly on different architectures. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I run my code for np.save l let you know

Comment: Can I use this yo save a list of numpy arrays?