# saving huge 2D (or 3D) numpy array efficiently as labels for DNN with bit exact precision

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, label

I am developing a DNN algorithm and am in need of saving thousands of 2D (maybe 4 channels of 2D) Numpy arrays as labels.  2000 X 2000 array of integers.

I am not sure what is the most efficient way (in terms of speed and storage space) to save these arrays. I have tried:
- Numpy save and load, resulting in huge file sizes (hundreds of Mbs for one array)
- skimage package's imsave and imload, which is much faster but lossy and changes the numbers when reading back. Generally any package I use for saving image is lossy.

Please advise.

Comment: You can try `np.savez_compressed`

Comment: h5py may also suitable for this task. You can use many compression algorithms with different compression efficiency and speed. I would recommend Blosc. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48997927/4045774