# How to create a large array efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, out-of-memory

Currently I have some tracks that simulate people walking around in an area 1280x720pixels that span over 12 hours. The recordings stored are x, y coordinate and the timeframe (in seconds) of the specific recordings.

I want to create a movie sequence that shows how the people are walking over the 12 hours. To do this I split the data into 43200 different frames. This correspond to every frame is one second. My end goal is to use these data in a machine learning algorithm.

The idea is then simple. Initilize the frames, loop through all the x,y coordinate and add them to the array frames with their respective timeframe:

```
>>> frames = np.zeros((43200, 1280, 720,1))
>>> for track in tracks:
>>>     for x,y,time in track:
>>>     frames[int(time), y,x] = 255 # to visualize the walking
```

This will in theory create a frame of 43200 that can be saved as a mp4, gif or some other format and be played. However, the problem occurs when I try to initialize the numpy array:

```
>>> np.zeros((43200,720,1280,1))
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 297. GiB for an array with shape (43200, 1280, 720, 1) and data type float64
```

This makes sense because im trying to allocate:

```
>>> (43200 * 1280 * 720 * 8) * 1024**3 
296.630859375
```

I then thought about saving each frame to a npy file but each file will be 7.4MB which sums up to 320GB.

I also thought about splitting the frames up into five different arrays:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((8640, 720, 1280, 1))
>>> b = np.zeros((8640, 720, 1280, 1))
>>> c = np.zeros((8640, 720, 1280, 1))
>>> d = np.zeros((8640, 720, 1280, 1))
>>> e = np.zeros((8640, 720, 1280, 1))
```

But I think that seems cumbersome and it does not feel like the best solution. It will most likely slow the training of my machine learning algorithm. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? The data you have described is *by definition* of the scale of 300GB – there is no way to make it smaller without it being different data. What kind of "different data" would you be fine with? For example, the array currently uses 8-byte float, but only stores 0 or 255 – which could be simplified to 1-*bit* 0 or 1. Would you be fine with compression? How about a different format, such as a sparse matrix / storing only set-or-unset coordinates?

Comment: Are the frames (lossless) compressible and do you really need 64bit floats? eg. trying for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761075/4045774 (For your application this  has to be adapted but it would be interesting which compression ratio is achievable)

Answer (score 0):

I would just build the video a few frames at a time, then join the frames together using `ffmpeg`. There should be no need to store the whole video in memory at once based on the description of the use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to split your data in different, small arrays, and that probably won't be an issue for machine learning purposes.

However, I don't know if you will be able to create these five numpy arrays as they will also take a total of 297Gb of RAM.

I would probably :

- save the numpy arrays as PNGs using for instance `matplotlib.pyplot.imsave`, or
- store them as short videos, as a person won't be seen more than that on your video anyway, or
- reduce the fps or the resolution if you really want the whole video in one variable

Let me also add that :

- The snippet of code you gave can be executed in a much faster time with `frames = np.ones((43200, 1280, 720,1))*255`, as intricated `for` loops are very expensive
- If you were to create an array by setting all of its coefficients one by one, it would be more effective to initialize it with `np.empty(shape)`, as it would spare you the time needed to put all the coefficients to zero only to overwrite them in your `for` loop