# Effective compression with h5py for dataset with a lot of repetitions

Tags: python-3.x, compression, hdf5, h5py, lossless-compression

I have HDF5 files that consist numpy.array with `dim = (N, M, Q)`, where N - is a number
of such matricies. The main property of them that values are represented as a power of two and have a lot of repeition, so what I definitely mean:

`[[0,2,4,16,1024], [2,4,16,512,128], [4,16,128,0,2048] ...]`

And I'm looking for good compression. I tested gzip and bzip2, but it seems they are nood good choice in this case. It seems that I need some compression with customer dictionary or something that can really compress good such datasets. I don't have good grasp of filters and compressers, so I decided to ask it while I'm reading different resources about it.

If you have any experience or you have any ideas/recommendations, I'll be very thankful for your help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which compression ratio do you want to achieve? You can for example try https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761075/4045774 with clevel=9 (BLOSC is also available in h5py via a workaround) Of course chunk-shape has also an influence on the result.

Comment: @max9111, hi i want to reach compression rate about 20 or more, at thic moment the best result is 12 (bzip2, bitshuffle). I decided to test all possible compressions, but I am far from desires compression rate.