# Fastest method of reading tensor objects from files in python

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, h5py

I am training PyTorch models on various datasets. The datasets up to this point have been images so I can just read them on the fly when needed using cv2 or PIL which is fast.

Now I am presented with a dataset of tensor objects of shape [400, 400, 8]. In the past I have tried to load these objects using PyTorch and NumPy's built-in tensor reading operations but these are generally much slower than reading images.

The objects are currently stored in h5py compressed files where there are ~800 per file. My plan was to save the objects individually in some format and then read them on the fly but I am unsure of what format to save them in which is fastest.

I would like to avoid keeping them all in memory as I believe the memory requirement would be too high.

Comment: You can save numpy arrays in a compressed format. The speed generally depends on the data. eg. This solution also outperforms image compression libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761075/4045774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data arrays are still "images", just 8-channel ones, you can split them into 3 image files

```
a = x[:, :, 0:3]
b = x[:, :, 3:6]
c = x[:, :, 5:8]
c[:, :, 0] = 0 # reduces the compressed size
```

and store them using the conventional image libraries (cv2 and PIL).

Images compress **much** better than general data (lossy 'jpeg' even more so), and thefore that reduces both the disk space and bandwidth, and has file system caching benefits.

Comment: I'm accepting this as I like the solution for my problem where the data is in this format. I suppose it would be possible to reframe any tensor object as (N,H,W,3) shape and just reshape upon loading it.