# Why is reading h5 files extremely slow?

Tags: h5py

I have a data generator which works but is extremely slow to read data from a 200k image dataset.

I use:

```
 X=f[self.trName][idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
```

after having opened the file with `f=h5py.File(fileName,'r')`

It seems to be slower as the idx is large (sequential access?)
but in any case it is at least 10 seconds (sometimes >20 sec) to read a batch, which is far too slow (moreover reading from an SSD!)

Any ideas?

The dataset is taking 50.4 GB on disk (compressed) and its shape is:
(210000, 2, 128, 128)

(this is the shape of the trainingset, the targets have the same shape, and are stored as another dataset inside this same .h5 file)

Comment: It depends on how much data you are reading, and (maybe the size of the file and dataset). How big is the batch size? How big is the dataset, 200k images = xx GB?

Comment: Indeed please tell us the dataset shape and batch size. Furthermore please give the dataset chunk sizes. And read about chunking [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage) if you haven't done so yet. Important quote: _...keep in mind that when any element in a chunk is accessed, the entire chunk is read from disk._

Comment: Ok, so the dataset is taking 50.4 GB (compressed using opt=9 max compression) and the shape is (210000, 2, 128, 128) for the trainingset (the targets have the same shape)

Comment: maybe I should add that: (this is the shape of the trainingset, the targets have the same shape, and are stored as another dataset inside this same .h5 file, there is also a small test set and validation set but their size is almost negligeable compared to the trainingset (they are 20k of size: (20k,2,128,128))

Comment: Check your chunk-cache size. You may be reading the entire file multiple times if you don't set up a proper value for that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405220/4045774 (In the meantime this was implemented in h5py). There are also much much faster compression algorithms available (BLOSC) exampe https://stackoverflow.com/a/48997927/4045774