# Why does pickle take so much longer than np.save?

Tags: python, numpy, save, pickle

I want to save a `dict` or arrays.

I try both with `np.save` and with `pickle` and see that the former always take much less time.

My actual data is much bigger but I just present a small piece here for demonstration purposes:

```
import numpy as np
#import numpy.array as array
import time
import pickle

b = {0: [np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])], 1: [np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([-1,  0,  0,  0]), np.array([ 0, -1,  0,  0]), np.array([ 0,  0, -1,  0]), np.array([ 0,  0,  0, -1])], 2: [np.array([2, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 1, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([ 1, -1,  0,  0]), np.array([ 1,  0, -1,  0]), np.array([ 1,  0,  0, -1])], 3: [np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([-1,  0,  0,  0]), np.array([ 0, -1,  0,  0]), np.array([ 0,  0, -1,  0]), np.array([ 0,  0,  0, -1])], 4: [np.array([2, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 1, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([ 1, -1,  0,  0]), np.array([ 1,  0, -1,  0]), np.array([ 1,  0,  0, -1])], 5: [np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])], 6: [np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([-1,  0,  0,  0]), np.array([ 0, -1,  0,  0]), np.array([ 0,  0, -1,  0]), np.array([ 0,  0,  0, -1])], 2: [np.array([2, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 1, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([ 1, -1,  0,  0]), np.array([ 1,  0, -1,  0]), np.array([ 1,  0,  0, -1])], 7: [np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([-1,  0,  0,  0]), np.array([ 0, -1,  0,  0]), np.array([ 0,  0, -1,  0]), np.array([ 0,  0,  0, -1])], 8: [np.array([2, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 1, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([ 1, -1,  0,  0]), np.array([ 1,  0, -1,  0]), np.array([ 1,  0,  0, -1])]}


start_time = time.time()
with open('testpickle', 'wb') as myfile:
    pickle.dump(b, myfile)
print("--- Time to save with pickle: %s milliseconds ---" % (1000*time.time() - 1000*start_time))

start_time = time.time()
np.save('numpy', b)
print("--- Time to save with numpy: %s milliseconds ---" % (1000*time.time() - 1000*start_time))

start_time = time.time()
with open('testpickle', 'rb') as myfile:
    g1 = pickle.load(myfile)
print("--- Time to load with pickle: %s milliseconds ---" % (1000*time.time() - 1000*start_time))

start_time = time.time()
g2 = np.load('numpy.npy')
print("--- Time to load with numpy: %s milliseconds ---" % (1000*time.time() - 1000*start_time))
```

which gives an output:

```
--- Time to save with pickle: 4.0 milliseconds ---
--- Time to save with numpy: 1.0 milliseconds ---
--- Time to load with pickle: 2.0 milliseconds ---
--- Time to load with numpy: 1.0 milliseconds ---
```

The time difference is even more pronounced with my actual size (~100,000 keys in the dict).

Why does pickle take longer than np.save, both for saving and for loading?

When should I use `pickle`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because as long as the written object contains no Python data,

- numpy objects are represented in memory in a much simpler way than Python objects
- numpy.save is written in C
- numpy.save writes in a supersimple format that needs minimal processing

meanwhile

- Python objects have a lot of overhead
- pickle is written in Python
- pickle transforms the data considerably from the underlying representation in memory to the bytes being written on the disk

Note that if a numpy array does contain Python objects, then numpy just pickles the array, and all the win goes out the window.

Comment: By 'objects' you mean methods, functions etc?

Comment: I mean any value that is not a numpy value. A value that triggers `.dtype.hasobject` becoming true. For example, `np.array([1, "foo"])` is okay, `np.array([lambda x: x + 1])` and `np.array([{}])` are not.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but what do you mean exactly by the last 2 examples "not being okay"?

anbd what do you mean by 'python objects have a lot of overhead'?

Comment: I mean `np.array([{}]).dtype.hasobject` is `True`, and thus `np.save` would use pickle to represent it instead its own representation, which in turn means it is actually slightly *slower* than pickle.

Comment: Regarding overhead, Python is a dynamic language, and Python objects need to have lots of extra info that C doesn't (because compiler takes care of code knowing where and what everything is). E.g. for `a = list(range(100))`, compare `sys.getsizeof(a) + sum(sys.getsizeof(x) for x in a)` (size of Python list in memory) vs `np.array(a).nbytes` (size of the same numpy array). If you do `np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8).nbytes`, even bigger diff. But change it to a non-numpy type (e.g. dicts), numpy stops being able to store them in-place, and stores pointers: e.g. for `a = [{i: i} for i in range(100)]`

Comment: and you need to start counting the python sizes again: `np.array(a).nbytes + sum(sys.getsizeof(d) + sum(sys.getsizeof(k) + sys.getsizeof(v) for k, v in d.items()) for d in a)`, which is not that different (or possibly even larger?) than the corresponding Python list (whose size would be calculated exactly the same way, except for `sys.getsizeof(a)` instead of `np.array(a).nbytes`).

Comment: In Py3, `cPickle` is the standard `pickle`.  `save` is the `pickle` format for arrays.  `save` uses `pickle.dumps` to write objects like dictionaries and lists.  So with a complex structure like `b` `pickle` and `save` end up writing nearly the same things.  But `save` has to first wrap the dictionary in an object array.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need better timings.  I also disagree with the accepted answer.

`b` is a dictionary with 9 keys; the values are lists of arrays.  That means both `pickle.dump` and `np.save` will be using each other - `pickle` uses `save` to pickle the arrays, `save` uses `pickle` to save the dictionary and list.

`save` writes arrays.  That means it has to wrap your dictionary in a object dtype array in order to save it.

```
In [6]: np.save('test1',b)
In [7]: d=np.load('test1.npy')
In [8]: d
Out[8]: 
array({0: [array([0, 0, 0, 0])], 1: [array([1, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 0, 0]), .... array([ 1, -1,  0,  0]), array([ 1,  0, -1,  0]), array([ 1,  0,  0, -1])]},
      dtype=object)
In [9]: d.shape
Out[9]: ()
In [11]: list(d[()].keys())
Out[11]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Some timings:

```
In [12]: timeit np.save('test1',b)
850 µs ± 36.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [13]: timeit d=np.load('test1.npy')
566 µs ± 6.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [20]: %%timeit 
    ...: with open('testpickle', 'wb') as myfile:
    ...:     pickle.dump(b, myfile)
    ...:     
505 µs ± 9.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [21]: %%timeit 
    ...: with open('testpickle', 'rb') as myfile:
    ...:     g1 = pickle.load(myfile)
    ...:     
152 µs ± 4.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

In my timings `pickle` is faster.

The pickle file is slightly smaller:

```
In [23]: ll test1.npy testpickle
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 5740 Aug 14 08:40 test1.npy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 4204 Aug 14 08:43 testpickle
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `pickle` works on all sorts of Python objects and is written in pure Python, whereas `np.save` is designed for arrays and saves them in an efficient format.

From the [numpy.save documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), it can actually use pickle behind the scenes. This may limit portability between versions of Python and runs the risk of executing arbitrary code (which is a general risk when unpickling an unknown object).

Useful reference: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30330699/8289095)