# why pickle loads numpy arrays much faster than numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I have examined [Why does pickle take so much longer than np.save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837627/why-does-pickle-take-so-much-longer-than-np-save) before posting question.
From the answers there, we could think that `numpy` should work faster with `ndarrays`.
But look at these experiments!

**Functions we test:**

```
import numpy as np
import pickle as pkl

a = np.random.randn(1000,5)

with open("test.npy", "wb") as f:
    np.save(f, a)

with open("test.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pkl.dump(a,f)    

def load_with_numpy(name):
    for i in range(1000):
        with open(name, "rb") as f:
            np.load(f)
def load_with_pickle(name):
    for i in range(1000):
        with open(name, "rb") as f:
            pkl.load(f)
```

**Experiment results:**

```
%timeit load_with_numpy("test.npy")
296 ms ± 1.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit load_with_pickle("test.pkl")
28.2 ms ± 994 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Why is that so?

Comment: We can't reproduce any of this without access to the files you're using, and you haven't shown the file creation.

Comment: Also, even what you *have* shown us isn't in a state where it could actually work. For example, `load_with_pickle` attempts to make use of an unqualified `load` function that was never imported or defined.

Comment: @user2357112 fixed

Comment: Increase the size of `a`, once it has 100,000 elements or so I'm seeing better performance from numpy.

Comment: @user2699 That's true, now i see. In the topic, i linked, it was said that pickle uses numpy to save and load numpy arrays, but seems like this is not true

Comment: The 2 files are close to the same size.  `np.load` can load both.  We can see from `np.load` code that it checks the first few bytes for a `MAGIC_PREFIX`.  Failing to find that it actually calls `pickle.load`.  `pickle.load` is compiled.  For a `npy` file, `load` uses  `np.lib.npyio.format.read_array` which you can read yourself.

Comment: My answer in your link gets faster pickle load times.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845434/901925