# Speed of writing a numpy array to a text file

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need to write a very "high" two-column array to a text file and it is very slow. I find that if I reshape the array to a wider one, the writing speed is much quicker.
For example

```
import time
import numpy as np
dataMat1 = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
dataMat2 = np.random.rand(2,500000)
dataMat3 = np.random.rand(500000,2)
start = time.perf_counter()
with open('test1.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,dataMat1,fmt='%g',delimiter=' ')
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)

start = time.perf_counter()
with open('test2.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,dataMat2,fmt='%g',delimiter=' ')
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)

start = time.perf_counter()
with open('test3.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,dataMat3,fmt='%g',delimiter=' ')
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)
```

With the same number of elements in the three data matrixes, why is the last one much more time-consuming than the other two? Is there any way to speed up the writing of a "high" data array?

Comment: Do you really need it as text?

Comment: You may want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329726/fastest-save-and-load-options-for-a-numpy-array) for efficient array I/O

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to write it as text rather than a binary file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [hpaulj pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820971/190597), `savetxt` is [looping through the rows of `X`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1420) and formatting each row individually:

```
for row in X:
    try:
        v = format % tuple(row) + newline
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
                        "format specifier ('%s')"
                        % (str(X.dtype), format))
    fh.write(v)
```

I think the main time-killer here is all the string interpolation calls.
If we pack all the string interpolation into one call, things go much faster:

```
with open('/tmp/test4.txt','w') as f:
    fmt = ' '.join(['%g']*dataMat3.shape[1])
    fmt = '\n'.join([fmt]*dataMat3.shape[0])
    data = fmt % tuple(dataMat3.ravel())
    f.write(data)
```

---

```
import io
import time
import numpy as np

dataMat1 = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
dataMat2 = np.random.rand(2,500000)
dataMat3 = np.random.rand(500000,2)
start = time.perf_counter()
with open('/tmp/test1.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,dataMat1,fmt='%g',delimiter=' ')
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)

start = time.perf_counter()
with open('/tmp/test2.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,dataMat2,fmt='%g',delimiter=' ')
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)

start = time.perf_counter()
with open('/tmp/test3.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,dataMat3,fmt='%g',delimiter=' ')
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)

start = time.perf_counter()
with open('/tmp/test4.txt','w') as f:
    fmt = ' '.join(['%g']*dataMat3.shape[1])
    fmt = '\n'.join([fmt]*dataMat3.shape[0])
    data = fmt % tuple(dataMat3.ravel())        
    f.write(data)
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)
```

reports

```
0.1604848340011813
0.17416274400056864
0.6634929459996783
0.16207673999997496
```

Answer (score 4):

The code for `savetxt` is Python and accessible.  Basically it does a formatted write for each row/line.  In effect it does

```
for row in arr:
   f.write(fmt%tuple(row))
```

where `fmt` is derived from your `fmt` and shape of the array, e.g.

```
'%g %g %g ...'
```

So it's doing a file write for each row of the array.  The line format takes some time as well, but it's done in memory with Python code.

I expect `loadtxt/genfromtxt` will show the same time pattern - it takes longer to read many rows.

`pandas` has a faster csv load.  I haven't seen any discussion of its write speed.

Comment: How does this answer the question asked?

Comment: @ScottHunter, it answers the `why` question, doesn't it?

Comment: It answers it *now*.

Comment: Just a comment, I find pandas write speed is actually slower than numpy. `np.save()` is an order of magnitude faster than either, if a csv format is not necessary.