# fastest way to convert list represented as string to list object

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In my code i am converting lots of list represented as string to list object (in a loop) like the following:

```
s="[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"
ast.literal_eval(s)
```

problem is, for a big list it takes lot of time.

is there any way to make this process faster?

Comment: Does your list need to be stored as a string? Where does your list come from? I'm assuming - a file?

Comment: yes, in a file.

Comment: Can you post the file structure? Just a few representative lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking of using `json.loads`. It's significantly faster than `ast.literal_eval` as the latter should go through more complex Python parser/compiler stuff.

Of course this is only fine if you have to store your data as string and you do want to stick with stdlib. If you can use binary formats, like some [methods of Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30329726/13944524) or pickle module, they should be much more performant.

```py
from ast import literal_eval
from json import loads as j_loads
from json import dumps as j_dumps
from pickle import loads as p_loads
from pickle import dumps as p_dumps

from timeit import timeit

lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4]] * 100_000
lst_str = j_dumps(lst)
pickled = p_dumps(lst)


def use_json():
    return j_loads(lst_str)


def use_ast():
    return literal_eval(lst_str)


def use_pickle():
    return p_loads(pickled)


print(use_ast() == use_json() == use_pickle())

print(timeit(use_json, globals=globals(), number=5))
print(timeit(use_ast, globals=globals(), number=5))
print(timeit(use_pickle, globals=globals(), number=5))
```

output:

```
True
0.13874139200015634
4.015027895000458
0.006450980001318385
```